# Rails (6.0). View each block element not recognized inside nested partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails beginner project
In a view that I want to show all results from two different models (MediaLink & MediaCollection)
I have successfully created a two dimensional array @ranked_media that holds

```
[0] is id from table
[2] is total_points
[5] is class name as a string.
```

Being that they are pulled from 2 different tables, the id can be repeated twice, but won't have the same class name if id are identical.

In my view (pages/media.html.erb) :

```
<div class="container">
    <% @ranked_media.each do |media| %>
        <% if media[5] == 'MediaCollection' %>
          <%= render 'media_collection_show' %>
        <% else %>
          <%= render 'media_link_show' %>
        <% end %>
        
    <% end %>
</div>
```

partial _media_collection_show.html.erb :

```
<h2 class="text-center mt-4 text-white">
     is a MEDIA COLLECTION of class :: <%= @media_collections.class %>
</h2>
```

partial _media_link_show.html.erb :

```
<h2 class="text-center mt-4 text-white">
  is a MEDIA LINK of class :: <%= @media_links.class %>
</h2>
```

At this point all is fine. The block is being generated 5 times and applies the output according to the each block. The partials also outputs the class name to make sure they all work.

**My Problem**

However, I can add this to the view (3rd line is the change) :

```
<div class="container">
    <% @ranked_media.each do |media| %>
      <%= media %>
        <% if media[5] == 'MediaCollection' %>
          <%= render 'media_collection_show' %>
        <% else %>
          <%= render 'media_link_show' %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

And it outputs media object.
But if try that in any of the partials like this :

```
<h2 class="text-center mt-4 text-white">
  is a MEDIA LINK of class :: <%= @media_links.class %>
  <%= media %>
</h2>
```

I get NameError in Pages#media
undefined local variable or method `media'

How can I access the media block element inside these two partials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By sending in local variables to the partials: `<%= render 'media_link_show', media: media %>`. In the partial you'd access it like so:

```
<h2 class="text-center mt-4 text-white">
     is a MEDIA Object of class :: <%= media.class %>
</h2>
```

Note the lack of `@`; in general it's bad form to access instance
variables in partials.

Your third line (`<%= media %>`) also does nothing for the functionality, and can safely be removed.

**Edit**: When a controller does `@items = ...` in an action, it sets `@items` as an instance variable; any view rendered from that action has access to that value, which is why your `@ranked_media` can be looped over.

Partials are meant to be re-used, and not necessarily by the same view/controller, so if a partial accesses an instance variable, like your `_media_collection_show.html.erb` does, then any view/controller that uses that partial will need to set the `@media_collections` variable.

To avoid this (a controller action should strive to only set one instance variable), you can instead *inject* local variables into a partial: `<%= render "partial_name", items: @items %>`. Here, we're setting the *local variable* `items` to be the value of `@items`. By doing this, any *view* that uses the partial can send in their own items into the partial, without the need for the controller to set a "magical variable" `@items`. You could, for example, do: `<%= render "partial_name", items: [1, 2, 3] %>`. You've *decoupled* the partial from the controller.

Comment: works!!! regarding @. Are you suggesting I should make the each block like this : <% @ranked_media.each do |@media| %> ?

Comment: Not really; I've edited my answer to explain it in a bit more detail.